# Googlechart as image tag with specific format ruby on rails

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I add a image tag with a google pie chart, until now I have installed the gem but I would like to also personalize the chart, the size, colors, tags, etc. I've tried using tutorial like rail cast but it is outdated and some don't work for me.

```
<%=image tag #googlechart %>
```

Comment: Please add some sample code to demonstrate the specific issue you are having.  Following the guidelines in this article will help you get the best feedback: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you installed the gem and used the command bundle install like shown below

Gemfile:

```
gem "googlecharts", :require => "gchart"
```

file.html.ebr:

```
<% require 'gchart' %> 
<%= image_tag(Gchart.pie 
            :size => '600x400', 
            :title => 'Title here',
            :data => [1,4,5],
            :legend => ['Parameter1','Parameter2','Parameter3'],
            :bar_colors => ['2EB82E','3399FF','FF471A'],
            :labels => [label1, label2, label3])%>
```

The chart has the format of the size, title, data, legend, colors and labels that can be personalized and is painted as an image in the html.

Comment: Thanks adding the require to the gchart helped me to load the chart and the formats are the ones i needed. I would like to see more styles that can be modified of this chart.